# Flutter: Activate multiple gesture detectors after long press

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an application where there is multiple cards in a grid that each have their own gesture detector. I want to be able to long press on one of the cards and then drag over the other cards and activate each cards gesture detector separately. I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

It might be too late, but use `onLongPressMoveUpdate(updates)` and check `localOffsetFromOrigin.dx` or `localOffsetFromOrigin.dy` for positive and negative values for left,right,up,down drag respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`GestureDetector` has an event `onPanStart` which might be what you are looking for. Listen to this event on the other `Cards` after the `LongPress` event is activated.

> **onPanStart**
>
> A pointer has contacted the screen and has begun to move.

or else there is another widget to look into, the `swipedetector`, [here](https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector)